# Incrementing IntegerField counter in a database

Tags: python, django, django-models, models

As beginner at Django, i tried to make a simple application that would give Http response of how many times content was viewed.
I have created a new `Counter` model, and inside, added IntegerField model `count`.

```
class Counter(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __int__(self):
        return count
```

In views, i made a variable `counter` out of `Counter()` class, and tried adding +1 to `counter.count` integer, but when i tried to save, it would give me an error that integer couldn't be saved.

so i tried saving class instead:

```
def IndexView(response):
    counter = Counter()
    counter.count = counter.count + 1
    counter.save()
    return HttpResponse(counter.count)
```

This method, would keep showing `1` and could not change after reload.

---

How would i change `IntegerField` model properly, so it could be updated after every view, and would be saved even if server was reloaded?

Comment: Every time you do `Counter()`, you are creating a new object in the database, where the value of the field `count` would be 0, and you are incrementing it by one. You need to fetch the same object again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The problem

Yes but you are creating a new `Counter` object on each request, which starts again at 0, that's your problem

```
def IndexView(response):
    counter = Counter() # This creates a new counter each time
    counter.count = counter.count + 1
    counter.save()
    return HttpResponse(counter.count)
```

What you were doing above would result in a bunch of Counter objects with `count = 1` in the database.

### The Solution

My example below shows you how to get an existing Counter object, and increment it, or create it if it doesn't already exist, with `get_or_create()`

First we need to associate a Counter to e.g. a page (or anything, but we need someway to identify it and grab it from the DB)

```
class Counter(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    page = models.IntegerField() # or any other way to identify
                                 # what this counter belongs to
```

then:

```
def IndexView(response):
    # Get an existing page counter, or create one if not found (first page hit)
    # Example below is for page 1

    counter, created = Counter.objects.get_or_create(page=1) 

    counter.count = counter.count + 1
    counter.save()
    return HttpResponse(counter.count)
```

### Avoid race conditions that can happen with `count = count + 1`

And to avoid race conditions use an [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F)

```
# When you have many requests coming in,
# this may have outdated value of counter.count:
# counter.count = counter.count + 1

# Using an F expression makes the +1 happen on the database
from django.db.models import F
counter.count = F('count') + 1
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, is there any other way to change IntegerField?

Comment: That's not the problem, you are already changing the `IntegerField`, just on a new object (database row) that starts with `count = 0` default each time. What you were doing was resulting in a bunch of Counter objects with `count = 1` in the database. My example shows you how to get an existing Counter object, and increment it, or create it if it doesn't already exist, with `get_or_create()`